Returning previously failed drive to an MD array
I have a drive that was failed and removed from an array due to link failures. After a good amount of testing, it appears the drive is fine and that the issue was likely due to a faulty SATA cable. I am preparing to reinsert the drive to the system and want to be sure to use the correct procedure to do so given that it is in a fairly inconsistent state by now. By my reading, it should be as simple as using the --re-add command. Is this a correct assessment? [I do have full backups to save anyone making the suggestion]

Use --re-add if you like. Success will depend on whether a write-intent bitmap is present and how it was removed from the array in the first place.
If you have any doubts regarding --re-add — because md metadata is wrong, or data on the drive can't be trusted after intermittent disconnects, or if you can't rule out that data was altered during testing, or other concerns — you can --zero-superblock the drive (wipes old metadata) and then --add it the oldfashioned way.
This would guarantee a full re-sync then.
In the end only you can make the decision.

In case of bad data on one drive, there is no safe alternative to fully resync that drive. mdadm inherently does not know which data is correct. repair simply assumes "all data is correct" and re-writes parity. If this assumption is wrong, you now have bad data on all drives and cannot recover. repair might be an alternative only if you could specify that in case of mismatch, only drive X should be rewritten, not the others; but repair has no such options so it can't be done.

The raid level (RAID 1, RAID 5, RAID 6) makes no difference. In a RAID 1 you'd have a 50-50 chance it would just happen to sync in the direction you want it to; RAID 5, RAID 6 repair rewrites parity on all drives vs. resyncing data+parity of just one drive. It's not "just the same". It's very different.
